Accessing ASP.NET web app via virtual domain (no-ip.com) with SSL
I am writing an ASP.NET web app that implements a webhook accessed from a remote location over SSL.
I am using a virtual domain from the no-ip.com service as the address of the webhook. The domain has a No-IP Vital Encrypt DV SSL Certificate.
I have set the external service to use the webhook url https://mydomain.hopto.org:41799.
On running the debug app over https from Visual Studio, the browser cannot reach https://mydomain.hopto.org:41799/swagger but it can reach https://localhost:41799/swagger/
On triggering the remote service to call the webhook, a port listener shows a client connecting and disconnecting but the call is not successful.
The app is running on my home computer so I have forwarded the relevant port (41799) on my router to my computer. The port has been opened in Windows Firewall. I have imported the .pem certificate file to the computer.
In the launchsettings.json file I have updated the applicationUrl to include https://mydomain.hopto.org:41799 as well as https://localhost:41799
I guess I am missing something to make allow https call to the app via the virtual domain to negotiate a connection but I am all out of ideas.
Thank you for any help you can offer.
EDIT: I have checked some other things. I have forwarded ports 443 and 41799 from my router to my dev machine. I also tried putting the dev machine in the router's DMZ. With the ASP.NET service running on my dev machine, I can detect the correct SSL certificate from a remote computer using the virtual domain, so the port forwarding seems to be working. I can access the webhook from another computer on my local network via the dev machine's local IP address using either port.
But what I still can't do is access the webhook via the virtual domain or external IP address from any device.
